# How to get the the date range of previous month or quarter for reporting in SQL Server down to the seconds

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date-range

We are creating a SQL report query for customers' SQL for sending out the generated custom SQL reports monthly, quarterly, or bi-annually as per the customer's agreements.

So need to calculate the date range dynamically when the SQL report is run for variables `@startDate` and `@endDate` up to the accuracy of the last second eg:

For previous month's report:

```
@startDate: 2021-11-01 00:00:00.000
@endDate: 2021-11-30 23:59:59.000
```

For previous quarter's report:

```
@startDate: 2021-07-01 00:00:00.000
@endDate: 2021-09-30 23:59:59.000
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of calculating the last instant of a period, just use half-open intervals.  eg

```
@startDate: 2021-07-01 
@endDate: 2021-10-01
```

then

```
select . . .
where Dt >= @startDate
  and Dt < @endDate
```

or

```
select . . .
where Dt >= @startDate
  and Dt < dateadd(month,3,@startDate)
```

etc.

Answer (score -2):

So finally after trying a lot of SQL query patterns including Calendar Tables, these simple queries seem to work best:

```
-- First and Last Day of last month
SELECT DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, 0, GETDATE()) - 1, 0) AS 'Last month start date'
    ,DATEADD(ss, - 1, DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, GETDATE()), 0)) AS 'End Date';

GO

-- First and Last Day of Quarter
SELECT DATEADD(qq, DATEDIFF(qq, 0, GETDATE()) -1, 0) AS 'Last Quarter start datetime'
, DATEADD(second, -1, DATEADD(qq, DATEDIFF(qq, 0, GETDATE()), 0)) AS 'Last Quarter start datetime';
```

Comment: This isn't a blogging platform. And your assumption about "last second" is incorrect. In general, you use an inclusive lower boundary (since every date begins at 00:00:00.000000) and an exclusive upper one to avoid the issues with accuracy based on datatype of the column - however unlikely that issue might be. Using the abbreviations for datepart rather than the readable values is "less than optimal" IMO.